# Is there a way to safely determine max textures of XNA TextureCollection?

Tags: c#, xna

I notice that the `TextureCollection` '`Textures`' of `GraphicsDevice`  has a private field `_maxTextures` which appears to have a value 16 when inspected in the debugger (at least in HiDef profile on my current machine), but I can't find any place where this is either documented or queryable.

Is there a safe way of knowing which indices of this object can be accessed, or under what circumstances this is liable to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need that. Usually there is no specific limit to how many textures you use. But "have" can mean different things. You can use as many textures as you have memory.
My guess is, that this property somehow referes to the amount of textures bound at the same time. For example in your active shader for multtexturing. Before XNA 4.0 you coud access this via

```
myDevice.GraphicsDeviceCapabilities.MaxSimultaneousTextures
```

now the caps are completely removed and its assured depending on the profile you use. Reach or HiDef. Afaik in these profiles the limits are somewhat hardcoded or predefined and can't be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually originally included more context about why I want this, but edited my question as it was looking like another tumbleweed badge for my collection. I have textures that are modified at runtime, so I need to make sure they are not bound while altering their data: I loop through to determine this. I assumed that it was related to the profile, but unlike other capabilities I can't see it documented anywhere.